# I have lot of pivots which i copied from one excel to another. I have to change the range. Is there ay short cut to do this huge activity?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

The question is based on pivots. When we copy the tab from one excel to another. The range still refers to the old file. How can I change the range of all the pivots by using any short cut?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the pivot tables refer to the same data range, you can easily change the Data Source.

1. Click in the body of the pivot table.
2. In the Ribbon Bar (under PivotTable Tools), click on Change Data Source.
3. Change the table range in the dialog box that pops up.

*If you have a different range for each pivot table, you either have to do this for each one or write a macro that will do it.*